# SUM select ranges of varying lengths in a single column using null/non-null values in second column to decide SUM indexes in an Excel formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

Example of format for the issue, I need to generate the third row that is a sum of each color block:

> [image]

I have an odd set of columns in a very large dataset, and I am not great at Excel. I could be way off here, and there is an easy way to do this.

I need a formula to populate column C with, that generates the values displayed in column C in the image. The logic should go something like this (in rough pseudocode):

```
If A2 is equal to "":
     C2 == ""
     If A2 does not equal "":
          while cells in col[A] greater than A2 are equal to "":
              C2 += B2...B3...B4 etc.
              if cell in col[A] greater than A2 does not equal "":
                   break
```

Each time the formula encounters a non-null value in column A, it should sum column B until a new non-null value is found in column A, at which point it should lose the old sum and restart the operation.

I have tried variations that are something along the lines of the following formula:

```
=IF(A2 = "", "", SUM(B2:INDEX(MATCH()))
```

But I simply cannot get an `INDEX(MATCH())` combo to return the appropriate cell value (in my example, the first index returned to denote end of the range should be B5) based on the values in column A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*There are many ways of doing this, following solutions posted depends on ones `Excel Versions`*. Methods shown for both `MS365` users as well `Excel 2010+` onwards users.

• Using `MS365` Functions --> `LET()`, `SCAN()`, `TOCOL()` & OfCourse `MMULT()` -- **Method One**

### [image]

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, A2:A13,
     δ, SCAN(,α,LAMBDA(r,c,IF(c="",r,c))),
     IF(α, MMULT(N(TOROW(δ)=δ),B2:B13),""))
```

---

- `α` -- A variable to hold the entire range of first column.
- `δ` -- A variable used to fill down the blank rows by the above values using `SCAN()` function --> `SCAN(,α,LAMBDA(r,c,IF(c="",r,c)))`
- Finally, using an `IF()` function to check whether `α` is `TRUE` and executes the `MMULT()` which performs a matric multiplication of two matrix one returned using the `TOROW()` & the variable `δ` with the second column `B2:B13` thus returning the summation and returns blanks when the `IF()` logic do not meet the criteria.

---

• Or,

Using `SUMPRODUCT()` & `LOOKUP()` functions -- Applicable from `Excel 2010+` onwards -- **Method Two**

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd> --> needs to fill down for the rest of the cells.

```
=IF(A2,SUMPRODUCT(
       (LOOKUP(ROW(A$2:A$13),ROW(A$2:A$13)/
       (A$2:A$13<>""),A$2:A$13)=$A2)*$B$2:$B$13),"")
```

---

• Or, **Method Three**

*However, if one is reluctant to use those above formulas, may opt in for solutions using **helper**/**auxiliary** columns.*

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=IF(A2,A2,C1)
```

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=IF($A2,SUMIFS(B$2:B$13,C$2:C$13,$A2),"")
```

---

**Note:** Both formulas needs to **fill down**, also once we have got the output, we can **hide** the helper column, screenshot attached.

---

Answer (score 0):

Without helper column, simple formula. Start from the last cell in column C, `C13` in this example and fill up.

```
=IF(A13<>"",SUM(B13:B$13)-SUM(C14:C$14),"")
```

[image: Sum Blocks]